# Create a step graph from a serie of data

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks something like this

```
depth <- c(300, 360, 420, 480, 500)
concentration <- c(-31.6, -31.8, -30.5, -34.2, -33.6)

dd <- data.frame(depth, concentration)
```

with the major difference that my real dataset is 3500 row long.
Is there a way to obtain a dataset that will allow me to plot them in a "step" graph instead, i.e. transforming the dataset in something like this that then I can plot?

```
depth1 <-c(300, 360, 360, 420, 420, 480, 480 ...)
concentration 1 <- c(-31.6, -31.6, -31.8, -31.8, -30.5, -30.5, -34.2...)
```

?

Comment: Have a look at package `igraph`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
plot(depth, concentration, type = "s")
```

[image]

Or if you prefer ggplot2, you can use `geom_step`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dd) + geom_step(aes(x = depth, y = concentration))
```

[image]

If you just want the data transformation that would give you the x,y co-ordinates of the steps, you could do:

```
dd2 <- data.frame(depth = c(rep(depth, each = 2)[-1], NA), 
                  concentration = rep(concentration, each = 2))
```

So if you plot it with `type = "l"`, i.e. as a line graph, you get the same result:

```
plot(dd2$depth, dd2$concentration, type = "l")
```

[image]